# Adding headers to CORBA messages?

Tags: java, header, interceptor, corba

I'm currently working in a java application using CORBA, and I would like to be able to insert special headers to messages when these messages are sent from the client to service (so that these headers are checked at the server). Is there a way to accomplish this? The closest thing I got is interceptors but I'm not sure whether I could add any headers to messages.

Comment: Yeah, you can add more service contexts, that are transmitted with the request, and available to server-side interceptors.

Comment: EJP is correct in suggesting Service Contexts as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only portable solution are the CORBA Portable Interceptors, see for example [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/corba-metaprogramming-mechanisms-part-1/184403860) for some high level information